# C Compiler Errors - Warning: Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast | Error: Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

Tags: c, compiler-errors

ANSWER: I wasn't properly initializing variables.

I need to remember how pointer declarations work in C.

This chunk of code is supposed to take in some command line arguments in the format of:

> ./foo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... (any reasonable number of arguments so long as they're divisible by 5

My plan is to have 5 int arrays of variable size to store the arguments for use in logic later. So if I have 10 arguments, I'd have 5 2-int arrays, and so on.

```
int* IP1, IP2, BID, PN, EID;
int i;

if((argc < 2) || ((argc-1) % 5) != 0)
{ 
   /* Some error statements */
}

IP1 = (int*)malloc(argc-1);
IP2 = (int*)malloc(argc-1);  //This is line 26
BID = (int*)malloc(argc-1);
PN = (int*)malloc(argc-1);
EID = (int*)malloc(argc-1);

for(i = 0; i < argc-1; i+=5){
  IP1[i] = argv[i+1];
  IP2[i] = argv[i+2];        //This is line 33
  BID[i] = argv[i+3];
  PN[i] = argv[i+4];
  EID[i] = argv[i+5];
  printf("%d\t", i);
}
```

Problem is, I get these weird errors

```
>cc foo.c -o foo
foo.c: In function â€˜mainâ€™:
foo.c:26: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
foo.c:27: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
foo.c:28: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
foo.c:29: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
foo.c:33: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
foo.c:34: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
foo.c:35: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
foo.c:36: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

And I have no idea what they're supposed to be or represent. I've looked it up and nothing's helped so far. I was hoping y'all could.

EDIT: For the record I tried commenting out lines 26-30 and 33-37 and it compiles fine. Just thought I'd add that for posterity.

Comment: As you already got answer, one more tip - aren't you allocating too few memory? it's in bytes, have to be multiplied by sizeof(int).

Comment: Probably. I changed it earlier when trying to fix the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
int* IP1, IP2, BID, PN, EID;
```

is the same as this:

```
int *IP1;
int IP2;
int BID;
...
```

You want this:

```
int *IP1, *IP2, *BID, *PN, *EID;
```

But more generally, try to avoid declaring multiple variables on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables `IP2, BID, PN, EID` have only type `int` not `int*`. You have to write the `*` in front of each of them.

Your approach suffers from the problem that the `*` binds only to the variable that is directly beneath it. So

```
int *intptr, intvar;
```

Creates a pointer to an `int` and a variable of type `int`. To have both pointers you should write:

```
int *intptr, *intptr2;
//for more clarity
int *intptr;
int *intptr2;
```

Or alternatively (but read the comments!):

```
typedef int* intptr;
intptr IP1, IP2, BID, PN, EID;
```

Comment: This would work, but it's often considered bad practice to hide a pointer behind a typedef.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes typedefs should only be used for basic types so one can apply `const` and `*` to them at will.

Answer (score 1):

In C Language terms, a declaration looks like this:

```
type-specifier declaration-specifiers;
```

The *type-specifier* is a lone type, in your case it is `int`. This is followed by *declaration-specifiers*, a comma separated list of *declarators*. A declarator is made up of not just the identifier it declares, but includes all the `*`, `[]` and `()` to make its declaration look like its use. With this explanation it becomes obvious what you declare with

```
int* IP1, IP2, BID, PN, EID;
```

It's an `*IP1`, which is a pointer to int, and the rest are declared as ints.
This is one reason, why seasoned C programmers recommend to either

- Move the `*` towards the identifier in the declarator
- Declare just one identifier per line

This is how I would write the declaration:

```
int *IP1, *IP2, *BID, *PN, *EID;
```